# Debug Assertion Failed while building SFML blueprint Asteroid game?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, sfml

I was trying to follow the SFML Blueprint book. I managed to remove all the errors but one error remains in the code.
I have tried to find about the debug-assertion-failed.
I think this issue is arising due to the lists one of them is getting emptied.

[image: The program crashes]

[image: The visual studio debugger says]

My code for the world.cpp

```
#include "World.h"
#include "Entity.h"

World::World(int x, int y) : _x(x), _y(y) {}
World::~World() { clear(); }

void World::add(Entity* entity){
_entities_tmp.push_back(entity);
}

void World::clear()
{
for (Entity* entity : _entities)
    delete entity;
_entities.clear();
for (Entity* entity : _entities_tmp)
    delete entity;
_entities_tmp.clear();
_sounds.clear();
}

void World::add(Configuration::Sounds sound_id){
std::unique_ptr<sf::Sound> sound(new    sf::Sound(Configuration::sounds.get(sound_id)));
sound->setAttenuation(0);
sound->play();
_sounds.emplace_back(std::move(sound));

}

bool World::isCollide(const Entity& other)
{
for (Entity* entity_ptr : _entities)

    if (other.isCollide(*entity_ptr))
        return true;
    return false;

}

int World::size() {
return _entities.size() + _entities_tmp.size();
}
int World::getX() const{
return _x;
}
int World::getY() const{
return _y;
}

const std::list<Entity*> World::getEntities() const {
return _entities;
}

void World::update(sf::Time deltaTime)
{
if (_entities_tmp.size() > 0)
    _entities.merge(_entities_tmp);
for (Entity* entity_ptr : _entities)
{
    Entity& entity = *entity_ptr;
    entity.update(deltaTime);
    sf::Vector2f pos = entity.getPosition();
    if (pos.x < 0)
    {
        pos.x = _x;
        pos.y = _y - pos.y;
    }
    else if (pos.x > _x)
    {
        pos.x = 0;
        pos.y = _y - pos.y;
    }
    if (pos.y < 0)
        pos.y = _y;
    else if (pos.y > _y)
        pos.y = 0;
    entity.setPosition(pos);
}
const auto end = _entities.end();
for (auto it_i = _entities.begin(); it_i != end; ++it_i)
{
    Entity& entity_i = **it_i;
    auto it_j = it_i;
    it_j++;
    for (; it_j != end; ++it_j)
    {
        Entity& entity_j = **it_j;
        if (entity_i.isAlive() && entity_i.isCollide(entity_j))
            entity_i.onDestroy();
        if (entity_j.isAlive() && entity_j.isCollide(entity_i))
            entity_j.onDestroy();
    }
}
for (auto it = _entities.begin(); it != _entities.end();)
{
    if (!(*it)->isAlive()){
        delete *it;
        it = _entities.erase(it);
    }
    else ++it;
}
_sounds.remove_if([](const std::unique_ptr<sf::Sound>& sound)->
    bool {
    return sound->getStatus() != sf::SoundSource::Status::Playing;
});
}
void World::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
for (Entity* entity : _entities)
    target.draw(*entity, states);
}
```

Code for world.hpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

#include "Configuration.h"


class Entity;
class World : public sf :: Drawable
{
public:
World(const World&) = delete;
World& operator=(const World&) = delete;

World(int x, int y);
~World();

void add(Entity* entity);
void clear();
bool isCollide(const Entity& other);
int size();

void add(Configuration::Sounds sound_id);

const std::list<Entity*> getEntities() const;
int getX() const;
int getY() const;

void update(sf::Time deltaTime);

private:
std::list<Entity*> _entities;
std::list<Entity*> _entities_tmp;

std::list<std::unique_ptr<sf::Sound>> _sounds;
virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override;

const int _x;
const int _y;
};
```

code for Entity.h

```
class World;
class Entity : public sf::Drawable
{
public:
//Constructors
Entity(const Entity&) = delete;
Entity& operator= (const Entity&) = delete;

Entity(Configuration::Textures tex_id, World& world);
virtual ~Entity();
//Helpers
virtual bool isAlive() const;

const sf::Vector2f& getPosition() const;
template<typename ... Args>
void setPosition(Args&& ... args);
virtual bool isCollide(const Entity& other) const = 0;

//Updates
virtual void update(sf::Time deltaTime) = 0;
virtual void onDestroy();

protected:
friend class Meteor;
friend class Player;
friend class Saucer;
friend class ShootPlayer;
friend class ShootSaucer;

sf::Sprite _sprite;
sf::Vector2f _impulse;
World& _world;
bool _alive;

private:
virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override;
};
```

Comment: What error? You ***must*** paste some relevant error ***as text*** in your OP (question).

Comment: There is no error in program. But when I run my code it says Debug Assertion Failed Expression sequence not ordered. and Visual Studio sets breakpoint pointing to World.cpp update(); inside for loop after the  for (Entity* entity_ptr : _entities)

Comment: It meant "add the errors from your screenshot as text". Please :)

Comment: When you see a message box, you can press Ctrl+C to make a text copy of its contents. Then Ctrl+V pastes into your question. Select the block and apply code formatting to ensure it renders as plain text. Never include code or errors as images.

Comment: ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP120D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list
Line: 1682

Expression: sequence not ordered

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

---------------------------
Abort   Retry   Ignore   
---------------------------

Answer (score 0):

```
if (_entities_tmp.size() > 0)
    _entities.merge(_entities_tmp);
```

This does not work. `merge` works with two **sorted** ranges. And your vector is not sorted. This is why you get an assertion.

If not sorting them is on purpose and you just want to concatenate the two vectors, you can do:

```
_entities.reserve( _entities.size() + _entities_tmp.size() );
_entities.insert( _entities.end(), _entities_tmp.begin(), _entities_tmp.end() );
```

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00434FA9 in Asteroid.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000010.

Comment: Where, which line? You need to write better questions, we cannot always guess what you are trying to say...

Comment: I replaced the line 

    _entities.merge(_entities_tmp); with _enties.insert(_entities.end(), _entities_tmp.begin(), _entities_tmp.end() ); the function _entities.reserve() will not work here as it is a std::list not a vector. and yes the new break point it entity.update(deltaTime) after Entity& entity = *entity_ptr;

Comment: So fire up the debugger and check what is in `entity_ptr`. Chances are it's not what it should be. You never showed us how things get into your containers.

Comment: I have uploaded my visual studio project would you like to have a look please

Comment: entity_ptr is an iterator used to iterate the list _entities it is declared in the for loop

Comment: We don't do that here, sorry. StackOverflow aims to be a place where people with the same problem can come to and find their solution and this will not happen if we do it in a private conversation. Please try to get your example as simple as possible and then ask a question again. Remember to post the exact error message and the exact line it appears in.

Comment: No it's not an iterator, it's of the type of your containers data. It's a pointer to an entity. We cannot possibly know if this is a correct pointer. Your compiler says it's not, so I'm inclined to believe it.

Comment: The exact error is "Unhandled exception at 0x00B47C8C in Asteroid.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00B47C8C." which is being caused due to entity_ptr at line no 64 in world.cpp.also i have updated the question with the Entity class

Comment: Please create a new question and make that **one coherent question**. For example "line 64" is completely not useful because I don't have your line numbers. Please take a small break, collect all the information and  then write a single, coherent, simple [MCVE].